# Using a function within Row function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following function in excel: MATCH(B3,ETF!$F:$F, 0)

Which spits out the row number of a particular value B3 like 49930.

In the cell below, I have the following:

=MAX(ROW(49930:77721)*(ETF!A49930:G77721=B3))

This spits out the last occurrence of cell value B3 in another range.

Instead of hardcoding 49930, is there a way for me to reference the value 49930, which is stored in B1?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Indirect Formula. I allows you to create references. Something like this for example (untested):

```
=INDIRECT("F:"&MATCH(B3,ETF!$F:$F, 0);TRUE)
```